# PHP reload elements without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have code generating a table from a database like this:

```
<?
  include 'conndb.php';
?>

<button id="ps">PŚ</button>
<button id="lgp">LGP</button>
<table align=center border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 style=\"color: brown;\">
<tr>
  <td width=25 align=\"center\">Lp.</td>
  <td width=570 align=\"left\">Nazwisko i imię</td>
  <td width=50 align=\"center\">Pkt</td>
</tr>

<? ///content
  $sql55="SELECT * FROM `grobar_IDs` WHERE `ps_m_s`!=0 AND `kategoria`=1 ORDER BY `ps_m_s` DESC LIMIT 5";
  $result55=mysql_query($sql55);

  $lp0 = 1;
  while($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($result55)) {
    echo "<tr><td width=25 align=\"center\">".$lp0++."</td><td width=570 align=\"left\">".$s['nazwisko']." ".$s['imie']."</td><td width=50 align=\"center\">".$s['ps_m_s']."</td></tr>";
  }
  ///end content
?>
</table>
```

And I want to change the content between `///content` and `///end content` after using these buttons - of course without reloading the page. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you about [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: __Never__ add codes in comments, __always__ [edit] your question.

Comment: this is what you want https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp